# Queue heap or stack

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, queue

Are queues allocated on the stack or on the heap?I want to use a queue inside a function:

```
void lee()
{
  queue<int>Q;
  //stuff
}
```

And i want to know if i need to do:

```
queue<int>().swap(Q);
```

at the end of the function to free the memory.If the queue is on the stack , then I don't have to free it because it will be deallocated when the function ends.If i am wrong with anything please let me know , i am still a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::queue` and all other STL containers follow [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and clean up after themselves after they go out of scope. `std::queue`'s members are allocated on the stack, but they likely contain pointers to heap-allocated memory, which will be freed when the object goes out of scope (in this case end of function). Note that if you operate on an unnamed `std::queue` like this: `std::queue<int>().some_method()`, the `std::queue` goes out of scope at the end of the statement.

Comment: Ohh , so if i use vectors/stacks/queues inside functions they will be deallocated when the function ends?I'm using the swap trick to free queues because that's the best method i have found on the internet.